# forming curl post with json data as swift http post

Tags: json, swift, http, url, curl

I have a curl post that I'd like to turn into a http url request in swift:

curl post (command line):

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization:key=SERVER_KEY" "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send" --data-ascii '{"to":"DEVICE_TOKEN","data":{"uid":"USER_ID"},"priority":10,"notification":{"body":"Hello","badge":"2"}}'
```

http request (swift):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: globalClass.getAppDelegate().global.sendUrl)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

var bodyData:String!

bodyData = "title=\(title)&body=\(message)&user_id=\(user_id)"

request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
```

how do I put the data part into the bodyData of the http request?

```
"data":{"uid":"USER_ID"}
```

I don't know how to form it since it is a nested structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 2**

Convert to dictionary:

```
let title = "somthing"
let body = "body text"
let params = ["title":mail, "body": pass] as Dictionary<String, String>
```

convert dictionary to JSON:

```
do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
```

Adding headers

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue(serverKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Edit:

convert this JSON to Dictionary:

`"notification":{"body":"Hello","badge":"3"}`

```
let notification = ["body": "Hello", "badge":"3"]
let data: [String: AnyObject] = ["notification": notification as AnyObject]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  do you know how I would form a nested structure, like this one?  "notification":{"body":"Hello","badge":"3"}

Comment: @mjpablo23, added to post